# How to use htaccess for Urlshotner?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on making friendly URL-shotner.

**what I trying to do is:**

http://www.example.com/link=ASRCD87

**To:**

http://www.example.com/ASRCD87

where ASRCD87 is dynamically generated shot-url it could be anything.

Here is what i had tried:

**.htaccess**

```
#Turn Rewrite Engine On
 RewriteEngine On

# NC makes the rule non case sensitive

# L makes this the last rule that this specific condition will match

# $ in the regular expression makes the matching stop so that “customblah” will not work

# Rewrite for index.php?link=xxxxxxx

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?link=$1 [NC] [L]
```

**index.php**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="long">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


// inserting link & new code
extract($_POST);
if(isset($submit))
{
$con =  mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");
$shoturl = strtoupper(substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(0,9999))), 25));;
$query ="INSERT INTO ushotner(longurl, shot) VALUES('".$long."','".$shoturl."')";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if($res)
{
  echo '<a href=http://'."$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]".'/url/'.$shoturl.'>http://'."$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]".'/url/'.$shoturl.'</a>';

    }
    else
    {
        echo "problem with query";
    }


 }

// getting the unique code and redirect the visitor
if (isset($_GET['link'])) 
{
 $con =  mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");
 $fetch  = "SELECT * FROM shotner WHERE shot = '".$_GET['link']."' ";
 $records = mysqli_query($con,$fetch);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
  {
    $final_url = $row['longurl'];
    header("location:".$final_url);
  }

}
```

**server details:** CloudLinux
   using HTTP/2 Protocol

**Folder Structure:** 
[image: see here]

**Table structure:**
[image: see here]

The Above htaccess code is work perfectly on localhost environment but after upload the code on the server its wasn’t.
let me know what the problem? where i getting wrong.
help is appreciated.

Comment: And what does "it isn't working on the live server" actually mean? Are we meant to _guess_ ? You need to tell us what the actual issue is!

Comment: oh, the .htaccess code is not working on live server

Comment: So it looks like that you have to enable the rewriting module, enable the application of dynamic configuration files (since you apparently did not place those rules in the http servers host configuration, why ever) and you need to take care that this file is located at the correct location and readable for the http server process.

Comment: currently the index.php file is located  in public_html/url/  Dir. you mean to place the htaccess & index.php into the public_html right?

Comment: I cannot tell you. What you now claim (folder `url`) contradicts what you said in your question. I do not know your setup nor your folder structure.

Comment: Ah, I begin to understand, you did not say in your question that the location of your application, its base path, differs between your local setup and that live setup. Sure, in that case you need to modify your rewriting rule accordingly. How should it know to rewrite to `/url`? And how should such a dynamic configuration file located in a folder `/url` rewrite requests to paths without a `/url` prefix in the path? It won't get applied. You need to think from the http servers perspective and think about how the request is processed.

Comment: BTW: it looks like your php code is open to sql injection attacts... you really should learn about the benefits of the combination of using "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to prevent that.

Comment: what the h**l someone attack on my website DDos! next time i never share testing URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187393/discussion-between-navjot-singh-and-arkascha).

Answer (score -1):

It's better to try using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php.

```
 <?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It suggests an alternate approach which might make sense as a comment, but it does not answer the actual issue. Also the claim that this function should be "better" is arbitrary.

Comment: Besides: this won't work, since you have to rewrite the incoming requests _first_, otherwise the http server will return a 404...